# How to find the current locale of the Android application

Tags: android, localization

I am interested in finding the locale in which the android app is currently visible to the user.

For example:let's say my Android application only supports English and French. I have mapped my default locale to English. Now the same application is being run on the device in Spanish locale. I can always find out the device locale using `getResources.getConfiguration.getLocales().get(0).getLanguage()`. This API would return 'es'

Is there an API that would return me 'en' code since the default resources are being used in the application?

> I am definitely aware of the workaround where I can add a language
>   code to the respective strings.xml and can match its value with the
>   current locale.

Comment: I think, you can add "en" with the values folder and you can set the Locale.setDefault() to use English.

Comment: @Varun -  I have updated my answer can you see my answer below.

Comment: @vasanth the answer still remain irrelevant to the question I posted.